# Trouble in saving data to DB table, getting error 'Call to a member function setData() on a non-object'

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am getting some trouble in magento development i am trying database operation with custom my module
trying to save info to database table but getting error

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in ..../magento/app/code/local/Dinesh/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php on line 13
```

my code is here
namespace/modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
        <models>
            <modulename>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model</class>

                <resourceModel>namespace_modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </modulename>
        </models>

        <namespace_modulename_mysql4>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <tablename>
                        <table>namespace_modulename_tablename</table>
                    </tablename>                        
                </entities>
         </namespace_modulename_mysql4>
</global>
```

Namespace_Modulename_Model_Transactions.php

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Transactions extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace_modulename/transactions');
    }
}
```

Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Transactions.php

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Transactions extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace_modulename/transactions', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Transactions_Collection.php

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Transactions_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace_modulename/transactions');
    }
}
```

Dinesh/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php

```
    class Dinesh_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     //$this->loadLayout();
     //$this->renderLayout();
      echo "testing<pre>";
        $paytransaction = Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/transactions');

         print_r($paytransaction);
         //$paytransaction->setData('entity_id', $name);
      $paytransaction->setData('order_id', '2752');
      $paytransaction->setData('transaction_id', '7527');
      $paytransaction->setData('paykey', 'dsfds');
      $paytransaction->setData('transaction_status', 'dfvdf');
      $paytransaction->setData('currency', 'ffg');
      $paytransaction->setData('amount', '145');
      $paytransaction->setData('vendor_mail', 'fdbdf');
      $paytransaction->setData('sender_mail', 'dfbfb');
      $paytransaction->save();

        //$load = $paytransaction->load('2');
        //print_r($load);exit;


echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Comment: the code you posted does not seam to have anything to do with the customer account controller. Check what code is at the specified line and how it impacts your module.

Comment: Beside the comment of marius, you should use Resource instead of Mysql4 if you are working with Magento 1.6+

Comment: last time i missed some points in question by mistake , so i edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you hacked the core. There is no setData inside of `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`. You need to fix your core hacks before we can help you.

`Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/transactions')` returns false, why this is the case can be either the namespace before the / is wrong or the class after doesn't exist.

I assume you didn't post your original config.xml, therefore it is hard to guess, whether you broke it while changing for this post or not.

The namespace before the / must be the node name in `global/models` which is in your case `modulename` and not `namespace_modulename` but as I said, maybe you don't understand what you are doing or you just made a mistake while posting.

If the model files are living in the right directory and have the correct name, which is `Namespace/Modulename/Model/Transactions.php` and not `Namespace_Modulename_Model_Transactions.php` everything is fine.

All this can be debugged, when you stick to [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Comment: last time i missed some points in question by mistake , so i edited the question

Comment: Updated my answer